# Error : Index was outside the bounds of the array in c#

Tags: c#, indexing, was

I'm trying write small program using c# interface concept for the area of circle & square.While Giving specific condition `if (args[0] == "S")` there is an error `IndexOutOfRangeException`:

```
if (args[0]=="S")
    fig = new Square();
if (args[0]=="C")
    fig = new Circle();
```

Comment: You are not checking if the args array has non-zero length. It would be preferable if you included your code here as text instead of linking to a image.

Answer (score 0):

That will happen if `args` is empty. You can't ask for the first element of an empty array, because there isn't one. You should check the length first:

```
if (args.Length == 0)
{
    // Maybe exit? Is it valid not to specify any arguments?
}
// Either use an "else" here, or if you've quit in the "if" block
// then you don't need to because you know that there's at least
// one argument by now
```